# the border-bottom is not displayed completely

Tags: css

I don't understand why the border-bottom is not displayed entirely in the menu?

Here is my result below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFwiA.png)

In this image, there is a space on the left that I would like to remove because it is not aesthetically pretty.

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar" style="border-right: 1px solid black" [ngClass]="{ active: showSideBar }">
    <div class="logo-details" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
        <span class="logo_name">
      </span>
    </div>
    <ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
            <ng-container>
                <div class="menu" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
                    <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i> {{ menu.name }}
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>

            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

style.css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 58px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background: #239cd3;
    /* overflow-y:scroll;*/
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


/* LOGO */

.sidebar .logo-details {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}


/* ACCORDION */

.sidebar .accordion {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


/* MENU TITLE */

.sidebar .accordion .menu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* ICON MENU TITLE */

.sidebar .accordion li i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2rem;
    left: -15px;
    /* left: 1rem; */
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar .accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
    right: 1rem;
    left: auto;
}


.sidebar .accordion li.active i.fa-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

The code is here for information -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ucmryq?file=src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html).

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Your icon is absolutely positioned at -15px. It does not affect the width of the menu item. You could just add 15px to the left hand padding of menu to leave room for the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a `padding-left: 2rem;` for `ul` element. Remove that.
2. Give that `padding-left: 2rem;` to the `li` element in `*ngFor`.
3. remove `border-bottom` from div and add to li.[image: See this Image]